# sklearn BaggingClassifier + n_jobs=-1 + Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, theano

I am using sklearn's BaggingClassifier to create a bag of 20 Keras NN predictions.
Keras has a sklearn wrapper, which works perfectly for everything!, but this BaggingClassifier seems to cause problems.

If I set the BaggingClassifier n_jobs setting to use only one core it works without problems! The problem only occurs if I want to use multicores.

I tried it with Keras Theano/Tensorflow backends, **both work if n_jobs = 1 but fail if n_jobs = -1**

FAILING:

```
bag = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=KerasClassifier(build_fn=createKerasTenserflow, nb_epoch=12), n_estimators=20, n_jobs=-1)
bag.fit(scale(X.values), y)
y_proba = bag.predict_proba(scale(Tx.values))

Error message:"TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(298,), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph."
```

It says its a Tensor error but it also doesn't work with Theano. I suspect that the parallel processing of BaggingClassifier requires to pickle the Keras model at some point and this causes the problem...?!

**Update**

I am pretty sure it's a pickle problem since after some investigation (with help of http://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html) it shows me:

```
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[([<keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x125dc3978>], [array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
    13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
    26,  27,  28,  29,  30])])]'. Reason: 'TypeError("can't pickle module objects",)'
```

Those are my 31 input features

**Update 2**

There is somehow a solution to this problem as poitned out by user crbrinton at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4274 but I am not sure how to tailor it down to my specific sklearn.BaggingClassifier scenario

Comment: Can you describe your problem in detail, preferably with codes, sample data and complete error messages.

Comment: @VivekKumar I updated the question, the code seemed irrelevant to me since it is working without problems if n_jobs=1. I also written down my theory regarding the root of the problem

Comment: It will not pickle but will clone the internal estimator.